# perl: capturing the replaced-with string

Tags: regex, perl

I have code in a loop similar to

```
for( my $i=0; $a =~ s/<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>/sprintf("&CITE%03d;",$i)/e ; $i++ ){  
    %cite{ $i } = $1;  
    }
```

but instead of just the integer index, I want to make the keys of the hash the actual replaced-with text (placeholder "&CITE001;", etc.) without having to redo the sprintf().

I was almost sure there was a way to do it (variable similar to $& and such, but maybe I was thinking of vim's substitutions and not perl.  :)

Thanks!

Comment: Do it the way @ikegami has it. If you do the loop this way, it will be an endless loop, always finding the first `<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>` Because `s///e` is not global, you'd need `s///eg` to move past that match.

Comment: This looks a bit like it might be `xml`. Is it? If so, the solution is pretty easy with a parser.

Comment: @sln, You are mistaken. Because the replacement will never include `<tag>...</tag>`, it' s not an infinite loop. It is, however, inefficient because the match starts from the start each time.

Comment: @ikegami - Yeah, my oversight.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $i = 0;
s{<tag>(.*?)</tag>}{
   my $entity = sprintf("&CITE%03d;", $i++);
   $cite{$entity} = $1;
   $entity
}eg;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a something of a hacque, but really wanted something a bit more elegant.  What I ended up doing (for now) is

```
my $t;  
for( my $i=0; $t = sprintf("&CITE%04d;",$i), $all =~ s/($oct.*?$cct)/$t/s; $i++ ){  
    $cites{$t} = $1;  
    }
```

but I really wanted something even more "self-contained".

Just being able to grab the replacement string would've made things much simpler, though.  This is a simple read-modify-write op.

True, adding the 'g' modifier should help shave some microseconds off it.  :D

Answer (score 0):

I think any method other than re-starting the search from the start of the target
is *always* the better choice.

In that vein and, as an alternative, you can move the logic inside the regex
via a *Code Construct* `(?{ code })` and leverage the fact that `$^N` contains
the last capture content.

Perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

my $target = "<tag>zero</tag>\n<tag>one</tag>\n<tag>two</tag>\n<tag>three</tag>";

my %cite;
my ($cnt,$key) = (0,'');

$target =~ s/
    <tag> (.*?) <\/tag>
    (?{
      $key = sprintf("&CITE%03d;", $cnt++);
      $cite{$key} = $^N;
    })
  /$key/xg;

print $target, "\n";

print Dumper(\%cite);
```

Output

```
&CITE000;
&CITE001;
&CITE002;
&CITE003;
$VAR1 = {
          '&CITE000;' => 'zero',
          '&CITE001;' => 'one',
          '&CITE002;' => 'two',
          '&CITE003;' => 'three'
        };
```

---

Edited/code by @Ikegami

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

sub f {
    my $target = "<tag>zero</tag>\n<tag>one</tag>\n<tag>two</tag>\n<tag>three</tag>";

    my %cite;
    my ($cnt,$key) = (0,'');

    $target =~ s/
        <tag> (.*?) <\/tag>
        (?{
          $key = sprintf("&CITE%03d;", $cnt++);
          $cite{$key} = $^N;
        })
      /$key/xg;

    print $target, "\n";

    print Dumper(\%cite);
}

f() for 1..2;
```

Output

```
Variable "$key" will not stay shared at (re_eval 1) line 2.
Variable "$cnt" will not stay shared at (re_eval 1) line 2.
Variable "%cite" will not stay shared at (re_eval 1) line 3.
&CITE000;
&CITE001;
&CITE002;
&CITE003;
$VAR1 = {
          '&CITE000;' => 'zero',
          '&CITE001;' => 'one',
          '&CITE002;' => 'two',
          '&CITE003;' => 'three'
        };




$VAR1 = {};
```

This issue has been addressed in 5.18.

---

Perl by @sln

See, now I don't get that issue in version 5.20.
And, I don't believe I got it in 5.12 either.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

sub wrapper {
   my ($targ, $href) = @_;
   my ($cnt, $key) = (0,'');
   $$targ =~ s/<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>(?{ $key = sprintf("&CITE%03d;", $cnt++); $href->{$key} = $^N; })/$key/g;
}

my ($target,%cite) = ("<tag>zero</tag>\n<tag>one</tag>\n<tag>two</tag>\n<tag>three</tag>", ());
wrapper( \$target, \%cite );
print $target, "\n";
print Dumper(\%cite);

($target,%cite) = ("<tag>zero</tag>\n<tag>one</tag>\n<tag>two</tag>\n<tag>three</tag>", ());
wrapper( \$target, \%cite );
print $target, "\n";
print Dumper(\%cite);
```

Output

```
&CITE000;
&CITE001;
&CITE002;
&CITE003;
$VAR1 = {
          '&CITE000;' => 'zero',
          '&CITE001;' => 'one',
          '&CITE002;' => 'two',
          '&CITE003;' => 'three'
        };
&CITE000;
&CITE001;
&CITE002;
&CITE003;
$VAR1 = {
          '&CITE000;' => 'zero',
          '&CITE001;' => 'one',
          '&CITE002;' => 'two',
          '&CITE003;' => 'three'
        };
```

Comment: The `my` for the three vars used in the `(?{ })` should be `local our`. (Move code into a sub you call twice to see that `my` is the wrong choice.)

Comment: I think `(?{..})` can referenced vars from the outter scope just fine. Setting them local within the regex, just cause them to reset upon unwinding a quantified scope. As in the case of a counter. Local regex declarations are only used in this case, where the outter scoped var is assigned the local val at the end of the regex.

Comment: I told you how to make the failure obvious. You obviously didn't try it, so why are you contradicting me? /// The fact that you don't even know the pitfalls of your approch just goes to show how complex it is. I recommend against using experimental `(?{ })` when is easily avoidable

Comment: Not sure what you mean, so you'll have to produce some code I can examine.

Comment: Literally just put your code in a sub and call the sub twice.

Comment: The whole thing? I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: `(?{ })` captures at compile-time like a named sub (unlike `sub BLOCK` which captures at run-time). As such, it suffers from the same problem as nested named subs.

Comment: I've been away from Perl for a while. I added a sub for you. Not sure what you mean by `(?{ }) captures`, do you mean the `$^N` variable. It is runtime . There are definitely _scope_ issues in Perl, but code constructs are pretty consistent.

Comment: And, I guess you could put `$cnt,$key` local to the sub now. Added that feature.

Comment: Capturing a variable is what allows a sub to reference a var even after it's gone out of scope.  `{ my $s = "abc"; sub f { say $s; } } f();`

Comment: Well, I found this `Due to an unfortunate implementation issue, the Perl code contained in these blocks is treated as a compile time closure that can have seemingly bizarre consequences when used with lexically scoped variables inside of subroutines or loops. There are various workarounds for this, including simply using global variables instead.` and I guess I never used sub lexical scope before. I guess they fixed it anyway, since I don't see the those warnings (bizzarr behavior so to speak). Anyway, don't throw out the baby with the bathwater.

Comment: Btw, to be honest, in the past I had seen this `will not stay shared at (re_eval 1) ` a few times, and even with globally scoped vars. Seems to happen when you call some perl intrinsic functions. And, moving them around or using a different function fixes it. I'd say for this case, it's all safe. Won't stop me from using code constructs, most needs are simple though.